# JSON valid numerical param in Perl

Tags: json, perl, rpc, bitcoin

```
my $client = new JSON::RPC::Client;

$client->ua->credentials(
 'localhost:8332', 'jsonrpc', 'user' => 'password'  
  );

my $uri = 'http://localhost:8332/';
my $obj = {
  method  => 'sendfrom',
  params  => [$account,$sendto,$btc,6], };

my $res = $client->call( $uri, $obj );

if ($res){
  if ($res->is_error) { print "Error : ", $res->error_message; }
  else { print Dumper($res->result); }
} else {
  print $client->status_line;
 }
```

Considering the code above $btc is accepted as a param if it is declared:

```
$btc = 0.01;
```

Not accepted if it is:

```
$btc = 0.01;
$btc = sprintf('%.8f', $btc);
```

Also not accepted if it is:

```
&ReadParse(*data);
$btc =  $data{'amount'};
```

Why is it happening? I need to take the $btc value from a html form, and ideally format the value.

The error being returned is "500 internal server error"

Comment: *"`$btc` is accepted as a parameter"* to what? What are you doing with `$obj` (which isn't an object, it's just a hash).

Comment: It looks like the problem is with the server. What is on the other side of `localhost:8332`?

Comment: @Borodin localhost:8332 is the RPC port from Bitcoin-Qt daemon.

Comment: The `sprintf` results in the *string* `"0.01000000"`. What happens if you set `$btc = "0.01000000"` and `$btc = 0.01000000`?. It may well be that the daemon doesn't like strings for this value. Why do you want to format it?

Comment: @Borodin "0.01000000" is not accepted, 0.01000000 is accepted. I wanted to format just to round the value when it is a caculation result but i don't really need to do that. However i need to get the $btc value from user input and even when a valid value is passed thru' &ReadParse, it is not accepted as valid.

Comment: That's very unusual behaviour (Perl converts between strings, integers and floats transparently) but you can coerce your values to numeric floating point by adding `0.0`. So use `0.0 + sprintf('%.8f', $btc)`, `0.0 + $data{'amount'}` etc. By the way, please don't call subroutines with an ampersand. Just `ReadParse(*data)` is correct.

Comment: @Borodin Thanks a lot, the  0.0 + solved the issue. I was two days stuck on it.

Comment: @Borodin Well :( Weird that it worked on a source code but not on another. Both are absolutely the same, when using json and handling $btc. May i think ActiveState Perl is bugged?

Comment: @Borodin it is not a scope problem but puting $btc close to the call function made it work. don't know what is going on but thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's very unusual behaviour (Perl converts between strings, integers and floats transparently) but you can coerce your values to numeric floating point by adding zero.

So use `0.0 + sprintf('%.8f', $btc)`, `0.0 + $data{'amount'}` etc.

By the way, please don't call subroutines with an ampersand. Just `ReadParse(*data)` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The service appears to be picky about whether it's been provided a string or a number. Use the following to force numification:

```
$btc = 0+$x;
```